# Query to cross-reference tables & count matches?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT a.title,
       a.spec,
       a.name,
       l.User AS CreatedBy,
       DateAdd ( "s", l.time, #03/01/1980# ) AS CreatedAt
FROM 
    (Reports AS a
      INNER JOIN
        AuditLog AS l ON a.id = l.id)
      INNER JOIN
        (SELECT min([time]) AS Mintime,
         id FROM AuditLog GROUP BY id)
        AS t ON (l.time = t.mintime)
      AND (l.id = t.id)
WHERE (((a.ACTIVE)='Y'));
```

The table `Reports` has 15000 records and AuditLog has 25800. But this query only returns 7800 results, and I figured there would be more (an audit is generated when a Report is created, so one would assume there's a matching audit for every Report).

What are some new queries I could make to research what is missing, such as record counts etc? I did try copying this query and using OUTER JOIN, but it gave me "Syntax error in JOIN operation". Most are active, so removing the WHERE clause is not the cause.

Comment: How many do you get if you remove the where clause?

Comment: @Laurence Only about 10 more.

Comment: LEFT JOIN, not OUTER. Try the query design window in MS Access. You can set up the tables in SQL view, including your subquery / derived table, using only commas to separate the tables, and then add the joins in query design view.

Comment: @Remou Tried that, almost worked and got a runtime error `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`

Comment: Check that the fields you are using in the joins are of the same data type. You can use a subquery to coerce a type, if you must.

Comment: @Remou Yep it's all text type. Maybe the subselect is the issue; editing my question.

Comment: `l.time = t.mintime` These do not look like text data type.

Comment: @Remou Sorry yes, `time` is Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using `Left Join`.
This will show all records in Reports, regardless of whether there are matches in the AuditLog table.

```
Select
  a.title, 
  a.spec, 
  a.name, 
  l.User AS CreatedBy, 
  IIf(IsNull(l.Time), Null, DateAdd ( "s", l.time, #03/01/1980# )) AS CreatedAt
From (
  Reports As a 
    Left Join
  AuditLog AS l 
    On a.id = l.id
  ) Left Join (
    Select
      Min([time]) AS Mintime, 
      id
    From 
      AuditLog 
    Group By
      id
  )  AS t ON (l.id = t.id) AND (l.time = t.mintime)
Where
  a.Active = 'Y';
```

Here's an extract from the database documenter feature of my test database:

```
Table: AuditLog                                             

     Name      Type          Size
     ID        Long Integer  4
     Time      Long Integer  4
     User      Text          255

Table: Reports

     Name      Type          Size
     ID        Long Integer  4
     Title     Text          255
     Spec      Text          255
     Name      Text          255
     Active    Text          255

Query: Test

SQL

     SELECT a.title, a.spec, a.name, l.User AS CreatedBy, DateAdd ( "s", l.time,
     #03/01/1980# ) AS CreatedAt
     FROM (Reports AS a LEFT JOIN AuditLog AS l ON a.id = l.id) LEFT JOIN (SELECT
      Min([time]) AS Mintime, id FROM AuditLog GROUP BY id)  AS t ON (l.id = t.id)
     AND (l.time = t.mintime)
     WHERE a.Active = 'Y'

Columns

     Name      Type          Size
     title     Text          255
     spec      Text          255
     name      Text          255
     CreatedBy Text          255
     CreatedAt Date/Time     8
```

I notice Access has added some more parentheses in. Also, the documenter missed the where clause for some reason. It's in the query definition.

Comment: That gives me `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'a.id = l.id Left Join ( Select` ...

Comment: Fixed this, Access needs more parenthesis than I thought.

Comment: That gives me the `data mismatch` runtime error as well. title,spec,name,user are Text and time is Number.

Comment: @JBurace I've updated the answer with the column definitions I used to test it.

Comment: I'm starting to think maybe it is hitting null comparisons?

Comment: I get `#Error` values in the `CreatedAt` column, but still get results with `Nulls`. However, I've updated the query to specifically deal with a null time.  This may occur because of the outer join as well as if there's a row with nulls.

Answer (score 1):

"*What are some new queries I could make to research what is missing, such as record counts etc?*"

How many rows from `Reports` do you expect in the query result set?  If it should be one row for each unique `Reports.id`, start by checking what you get from this query:

```
SELECT r.id, Count(*) AS num_matches
FROM [Reports] AS r
WHERE r.ACTIVE='Y'
GROUP BY r.id;
```

It could also be helpful to examine the subquery result set separately.

```
SELECT id, Min([time]) AS Mintime, Count(*) AS num_rows
FROM AuditLog
GROUP BY id;
```

Beyond those suggestions, I got lost trying to infer your intended goal from the SQL.  However, I wanted to warn you there may be trouble with this field expression if you switch to `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

```
DateAdd("s", l.time, #03/01/1980#) AS CreatedAt
```

With a `LEFT JOIN`, you may have rows with Null for `l.time`.  The following expression throws "Invalid Use of Null".

```
DateAdd("s", Null, #03/01/1980#)
```

If you're running into that problem, move the `DateAdd` expression into a subquery where you ensure it's fed only non-Null values.  Or use `DateAdd` inside an `IIf()` expression to protect it from Nulls.

```
IIf([time] Is Null, Null, DateAdd("s", [time], #03/01/1980#)) AS CreatedAt
```